# Health bar is reducing but OXYGEN bar isn't at different objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game, like a fire fighter, I have made health and oxygen object and place 2 scripts on it, below is my code of oxygen and health scripts. I am facing problem that, when I place this duplicate object in any other position, like have 2 fires on map, then at first object health and oxygen works fine, but at 2nd object, health bar works fine but oxygen bar doesn't work fine.

here is the script of Oxygen.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class OXYGEN : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform Player;
public Transform OxygenBar;
public Transform TextIndicator;
[SerializeField] private float currentAmount;
[SerializeField] private float speed;
// method to check that player is range of fire flames or not
void Update () {
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);
    if(dist<3 )
    {
        reducetheoxygen();
    }
    if (dist > 3) {
        increaseOxygen ();
    }
}
//method to decrese the oxygen
void reducetheoxygen () {

    if (currentAmount > 0) {
        currentAmount-= speed *Time.deltaTime;
        TextIndicator.GetComponent<Text>().text=((int)currentAmount).ToString()+" %";
        } 
    else {
        TextIndicator.GetComponent<Text>().text="Oxygen End!!!!";
        Application.LoadLevel (4);
    }
    OxygenBar.GetComponent<Image> ().fillAmount = currentAmount / 100;
}

//method to increase the oxygen
void increaseOxygen () {

    if (currentAmount == 100 || currentAmount >100) {
    }
    else{
        currentAmount+= speed *Time.deltaTime;
        TextIndicator.GetComponent<Text>().text=((int)currentAmount).ToString()+" %";
    }
    OxygenBar.GetComponent<Image> ().fillAmount = currentAmount / 100;
}
}
```

Here is the script of Health

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class health : MonoBehaviour {

// these are variables
public Transform Player;
public Transform HealthBar;
public Transform TextIndicator;
[SerializeField] private float currentAmount;
[SerializeField] private float speed;

// method for checking distance that player in range of fire flames
void Update () {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(Player.position, transform.position);

    if(distance<2 )
    {
        decreaseHealth();
    }
}
//method for decresing health
void decreaseHealth () {

    if (currentAmount > 0) {
        currentAmount -= speed;
        TextIndicator.GetComponent<Text>().text=((int)currentAmount).ToString()+"%";
    } else {

        TextIndicator.GetComponent<Text>().text="You are Dead!!!!!";
        Application.LoadLevel (4);
    }
    HealthBar.GetComponent<Image> ().fillAmount = currentAmount / 100;
}
}
```

Comment: This English makes my head hurt.

Comment: @FarhanAli I'm just messing with you man, relax, don't get demotivated because someone on the internet is mean to you. It's the internet. I can speak Arabic and English fluently, so no need to get twisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort out.
In Update function, distance function conflicts with others so that instead of Distance, I have used OnTriggerStay and it works fine .

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider obj)
 {

    if (obj.gameObject.tag == "coin"    ||obj.gameObject.tag=="coin1"||obj.gameObject.tag=="coin2") {
        Debug.Log ("colide");
        collided = true;
}
}
void OnTriggerExit()
{

    collided = false;
}
```